# 'Yes/No Attribute' in magento - how to get text value for a store view

Tags: magento-1.7, product-attribute, store-view

I wonder how I can get value of an yes/no attribute for a specifical store view in magento.

I've tried that way:

```
$store_vies_val = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($product_id, 'store_view_attr', $store_id);
```

but it returns nothing on displaying.

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: By value due you mean to say the attribute label or the actual value ie: yes/no ?

Comment: I mean its actual value. Yes/No, or, at least, 1/0

Comment: For Yes/No type its actual value will be 1 and 0.. do you need that? I guess you mean to say the attribute label right?

Comment: The code I wrote earlier doesn't return 1/0 neither true/false. I want to detect, if this atttribute's value is 'Yes' for this product in actual store view.

Comment: what about the attribute having set "visible on frontend" to yes?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution:

```
$custom = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod_id);
$store_vies_val = $custom->getAttributeText('store_view_attr');
if (($store_vies_val == 'No'){
...
}
```